# chef-client does not start service

Tags: ruby, apache, chef-infra

I'm using opscode tutorial on chef to start a service from a cookbook.  The service is apache2 and the cookbook is named "learn_chef_apache2"

```
package 'apache2'

service 'apache2' do
    action [:start, :enable]
end

template '/var/www/html/index.html' do
    source 'index.html.erb'
end
```

From my understanding, this is supposed to install apache2 if it's not installed, start and enable apache2 if it's not running and create that index.html file in /var/www/html/ folder.

This does report that it runs successfully.  However, this is my result.

```
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ sudo chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[learn_chef_apache2]'
[2015-03-13T22:13:55-04:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
Starting Chef Client, version 12.0.3
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["learn_chef_apache2"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - learn_chef_apache2
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 3 resources
Recipe: learn_chef_apache2::default
  * apt_package[apache2] action install (up to date)
  * service[apache2] action start (up to date)
  * service[apache2] action enable (up to date)
  * template[/var/www/html/index.html] action create (up to date)

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 0/4 resources updated in 1.916971556 seconds
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ service apache2 status * apache2 is not running
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$
```

The tutorial is found here:  https://learn.chef.io/learn-the-basics/ubuntu/make-your-recipe-more-manageable/

---

```
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ chef
chef         chef-apply   chef-client  chef-shell   chef-solo    
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ chef
chef         chef-apply   chef-client  chef-shell   chef-solo    
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ chef
chef         chef-apply   chef-client  chef-shell   chef-solo    
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ chef-client -v
Chef: 12.0.3
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$
```

Comment: Are the same results checking apache2 status as root? i.e.: `sudo service apache2 status`

Comment: That's correct, it's the same with "sudo service apache2 status"

Comment: ubuntu@chefnode:~$ sudo service apache2 status
● apache2.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like when initiating a "stop" via a recipe or by `sudo service apache2 stop`

Another recipe will "NOT" be able to start the service back up.  Rather than using "start" I had to use "restart" to get it to work.

```
    package 'apache2'

service 'apache2' do
    action [:stop, :enable]
end

template '/var/www/html/index.html' do
    source 'index.html.erb'
end
```

---

```
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ sudo chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[learn_chef_apache2]'
[2015-03-14T11:28:28-04:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
Starting Chef Client, version 12.0.3
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["learn_chef_apache2"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - learn_chef_apache2
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 3 resources
Recipe: learn_chef_apache2::default
  * apt_package[apache2] action install (up to date)
  * service[apache2] action stop
    - stop service service[apache2]
  * service[apache2] action enable (up to date)
  * template[/var/www/html/index.html] action create (up to date)

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 1/4 resources updated in 3.538150111 seconds
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ 
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ sudo service apache2 status * apache2 is not running
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$
```

---

Here I initiate the "start" action which does NOT work.

```
package 'apache2'

service 'apache2' do
    action [:start, :enable]
end

template '/var/www/html/index.html' do
    source 'index.html.erb'
end
```

---

```
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ sudo chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[learn_chef_apache2]'
[2015-03-14T11:35:43-04:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
Starting Chef Client, version 12.0.3
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["learn_chef_apache2"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - learn_chef_apache2
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 3 resources
Recipe: learn_chef_apache2::default
  * apt_package[apache2] action install (up to date)
  * service[apache2] action start (up to date)
  * service[apache2] action enable (up to date)
  * template[/var/www/html/index.html] action create (up to date)

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 0/4 resources updated in 2.524905132 seconds
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ sudo service apache2 status * apache2 is not running
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$
```

---

And here I perform a "restart" which does work.

```
package 'apache2'

service 'apache2' do
    action [:restart, :enable]
end

template '/var/www/html/index.html' do
    source 'index.html.erb'
end
```

---

```
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ sudo chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[learn_chef_apache2]'
[2015-03-14T11:32:52-04:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
Starting Chef Client, version 12.0.3
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["learn_chef_apache2"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - learn_chef_apache2
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 3 resources
Recipe: learn_chef_apache2::default
  * apt_package[apache2] action install (up to date)
  * service[apache2] action restart
    - restart service service[apache2]
  * service[apache2] action enable (up to date)
  * template[/var/www/html/index.html] action create (up to date)

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 1/4 resources updated in 3.468081078 seconds
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$ sudo service apache2 status
 * apache2 is running
akhter@akhter-GA-990FXA-UD3:~/chef-repo/cookbooks$
```

---

Comment: In my case apache in not getting installed nor getting error when I bootstrap node : # knife node show sg_poc_ubu_ChefNode2                                                            Node Name:   sg_poc_ubu_ChefNode2
Environment: _default
FQDN:        chefnode.node.com
IP:          XX.X.X1.55
Run List:    recipe[learn_chef_apache2]
Roles:
Recipes:     learn_chef_apache2, learn_chef_apache2::default
Platform:    ubuntu 16.04
Tags:

Comment: u# sudo service apache2 status
● apache2.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: I ran : # knife bootstrap MYIP  --ssh-user ubuntu  -i /root/.ssh/keytest_win_singreg.pem --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name sg_poc_ubu_ChefNode2   --run-list 'recipe[learn_chef_apache2]'